# AWS Amplify Deployment

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm having a problem deploying to Amplify. Before that, I deployed to heroku, and there were no problems. I have a react application that uses express on the backend.

For Heroku, the following algorithm works. I install the dependencies for the server `npm install` , then go to the client folder and install the dependencies for the frontend `npm install`. Then the frontend of application is built `npm run build`.

At the root of my application, I have a procfile where it says `web: npm start`. After deploying this scenario, the server starts up in production mode and gives me the builded `index.html` from the `client/build` folder. Things are good.

OK. For deploying to Amplify, I try to use this `amplify.yml`

```
version: 1
env:
  variables:
    PROD: true
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands: []
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - cd client
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: client/build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The build is going well, and I can go to the link and see my application. But only the frontend was deployed. Requests to my server are not working